# mac address order

Tags: mac-address, endianness

I found out MAC address of my net device in ifconfig -a - HWaddr 00:1a:92:9c:9b:bb

How can I relate to this address in my code?

```
struct ethhdr {
        unsigned char   h_dest[ETH_ALEN];       /* destination eth addr */
        unsigned char   h_source[ETH_ALEN];     /* source ether addr    */
        __be16          h_proto;                /* packet type ID field */
} __attribute__((packed));
```

I'm endeavouring to write to h_dest

```
memcpy(eth->h_dest,dest_mac,ETH_ALEN);
```

but I do not know in what order of bytes and bites must I pass the MAC-address value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They should be in left-to-right order, so `h_dest[0] = 0x00`.

Comment: and what about next bytes h_dest[1] = 0x1a, h_dest[2] = 0x92 ? Am I right?

Comment: Yes. Isn't that what left-to-right means? I was just getting you started to know which end is which.